# How to cast an object to the class returned by getClass()

Tags: java, generics, casting

```
ProtostuffIOUtil.mergeFrom(data,o,RuntimeSchema.getSchema(o.getClass()));
```

How to cast Object to getClass() Class. With the above method call, I will get a compile error because the method requires that the o variable is of the same class as the o.getClass() parameter. How does one get around this?

Comment: Class clazz=o.getClass();
ProtostuffIOUtil.mergeFrom(data,clazz.cast(o),RuntimeSchema.getSchema(clazz));

Comment: You should update your question to add which language you are using and also update the tag with a relevant value. That way more people will notice your question and provide answers.

Comment: If you manage to solve your own question, post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Class clazz = o.getClass();
ProtostuffIOUtil.mergeFrom(data, clazz.cast(o), RuntimeSchema.getSchema(clazz));
```

Answer (score 1):

Cast an object to the class from getClass() using the cast() method:

`myObj.getClass().cast(myObj)`